# Ambiguous reference to member upload alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am receiving this error when trying to upload a picture to my web server. I just copied and pasted the alamofire sample from github and I receive an error right away. My code is as follows:

```
  let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picOutlet.image, 0.5)


    Alamofire.upload(.POST, "phpurlhere", file: photo)
        .progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
            print(totalBytesWritten)

            // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
            // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("Total bytes written on main queue: \(totalBytesWritten)")
            }
        }
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

**UPDATE**: I added JPEG representation to pass to alamofire function but still getting same error.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:_:headers:file:)'

Comment: Why are you using `phpurlhere` on the url parameter instead the url?

Comment: I just wanted to remove my actual web url.

Comment: Please can you share your complete ***.swift** file where the function is declared?

Comment: @IBAction func picUpload(sender: AnyObject) {
        let photo = picOutlet.image
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, "https:/google.php", file: photo)
            .progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
                print(totalBytesWritten)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Total bytes written on main queue: \(totalBytesWritten)")
                }
            }
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
        }
    }

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you using ?

Comment: I am using Version 3.4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `upload` function:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "phpurlhere", file: photo)
```

is expecting an object of type `NSURL` for the `file:` parameter. You are giving it a `UIImage`.

If your goal is to upload `picOutlet.image` using the `upload` function, try the following:

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picOutlet.image, 0.5)

Alamofire.upload(.POST, "phpurlhere", data: data)
    .progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
        print(totalBytesWritten)

        // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
        // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("Total bytes written on main queue: \(totalBytesWritten)")
        }
    }
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: I still receive same error message after making changes.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 Alamofire.upload(photoURL, to: "phpurlhere", method: .post, headers:nil)
  .uploadProgress { progress in // main queue by default
            progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
   }
  .downloadProgress { progress in // main queue by default
     print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
  }
  .responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
  }
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.